# How to automate Y/N in vssadmin.exe

Tags: windows, command-line

I tried different arguments in vssadmin such as:

```
vssadmin Delete Shadows /Shadow="{Your Shadow ID}"
```

but when I add some options like `/Quite` like this:

```
vssadmin Delete Shadows /Shadow="{Your Shadow ID}" /Quite
```

it doesnt work...

I also tried:

```
vsaddmin Delete Shadows /All /Quite
```

But still no luck, are there any flags/options to use in order to make this automated to 'Y' or 'yes' without prompting?

Comment: `echo y|vssadmin delete ...`  ?

Comment: It's **`/Quiet`**, `vssadmin delete shadows /for=<ForVolumeSpec> [/oldest | /all | /shadow=<ShadowID>] [/quiet]`